# React does not update polygons in svg when component is defined outside of function (hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, react-hooks

Hello when I want to render an array Polygon inside SVG is works only when the component is defined inside the Component:

This works:

```
function Polygons() {
  const Polygon1 = ({ points, key }) => {
    return <polygon key={key} stroke="blue" points={points} />;
  };

  const [polygons, setPolygons] = useState([]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <svg width="500px" height="500px" version="1.1">
          {polygons.map((polygon, i) => {
            return <Polygon1 key={`polygon-${i}`} points={polygon.points} />;
          })}
        </svg>
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setPolygons([...polygons, { points: [10, 10] }]);
        }}
      >
        Add Polygon
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          if (!polygons.length) {
            alert("Please add first Polygon");
            return;
          }
          const lastPolygon = Object.assign({}, polygons[polygons.length - 1]);
          lastPolygon.points.push([Math.random() * 500, Math.random() * 500]);
          const newPolygons = [...polygons];
          newPolygons[newPolygons.length - 1] = lastPolygon;
          setPolygons(newPolygons);
        }}
      >
        Add Point
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and this does not work:

```
const Polygon1 = ({ points, key }) => {
  return <polygon key={key} stroke="blue" points={points} />;
};

function Polygons() {
  const [polygons, setPolygons] = useState([]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <svg width="500px" height="500px" version="1.1">
       ....
```

Can somebody explain me this behaviour and how can I solve this problem? I dont want to define the component inside another component.
I created a codesandbox, so you see the problem: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-forked-5ustk?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: You have an error in your second example: _"Polygon1: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned."_ --- I don't think you need the key inside the `Polygon1` component.

Comment: ok thank you. But this does not solve the problem...

Comment: That's why I commented not answered ;)

Comment: Don't remove the key from within the map. Once that is put back, the polygons _do_ render.

Comment: thank you! But why does it dont work with `polygon-${index}`? It works only with `polygon-${Math.random()}`

Comment: I would suggest reading more about [react keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Comment: I understand the general purpose of keys. It dont understand why it does not work with `polygon-${i}`? This is a unique name...

Comment: It might not be. I also don't know what you mean by "doesn't work". When I tried, the polygons rendered (they were invisible).